# How to check null column values in SQL Database, C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I'm using dataGridView in Windows Forms to show the database and want to color it. If [Solver] column is NULL it should paint LightSalmon, else LightGreen. However even if the column value is NULL it still see it as not null and paint into LightGreen.

```
This is my table:
      [Id]
      [Employee]
      [Section]
      [Machine]
      [Station]
      [MachNo]
      [Area]
      [Type]
      [Desc]
      [Recommendation]
      [Date]
      [Solver]
      [Process]


public void Color()
{
    for(int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows[11]))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }   
}
```

Comment: GRidView.Column datatype is not same to DBNull

Comment: Also try implementing `dataGridView1.Refresh()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[Solver]` (11th column) is a column not a row, so you need to check that column of each row is null or not

```
public void Color()
{
    for(int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == null || dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == DBNull.Value)
        {
             dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightSalmon;
        }    
        else
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather use the `Cells` property on that row like

```
if (DBNull.Value.Equals(dataGridView1.Rows.Cells[11].Value))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like below

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == null ? 
                                                          Color.LightSalmon : Color.LightGreen
```

or

```
dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == DBNull.Value ? 
                                                  Color.LightSalmon : Color.LightGreen
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {  
        if (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == null || 
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value == DBNull.Value)
    {
         dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }    
    else
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[i].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```